# Is there a link between hair color and the number of hair follicles?

Tags: hair

I've heard that people with blond hair usually have significantly more strands of hair. I searched around online, but I can't find anything outside of some unsourced answers to more more broad Q&A sites. Is there any proof that the number of hair strands or follicles are related to the color of your hair?

One example of such a claim is from [StyleList](http://www.stylelist.com/read/blondes-vs-brunettes-what-your-hair-color-says-about-you/):

> Fun fact! Natural blondes have significantly more hair than brunettes,
>   because evolutionary science tells us that hair evolved in part to
>   protect our scalp from the sun's rays. With less pigmentation than
>   brunettes, blondes developed more hair to get that protective barrier.

Comment: If you can't find a reputable source, then I would venture it is not worth debating...

Comment: @AthomSfere We don't require the claims that we examine to come from reliable sources.

Comment: @AthomSfere We don't require a reputable source for a question, that would rather defeat the purpose of the site. We require notability, and I've added a quote to establish that. But notability can (and often does) come from rather unreputable, but still popular sources.